# moment.js returns "Invalid date" for last day of March and August

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

When I pass Year, Month, Day as strings into the moment.js date constructor to get the last day of the month, it returns "Invalid date" for March and August:

```js
moment(["2022","0","31"]).toISOString()
"2022-01-31T06:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","1","28"]).toISOString()
"2022-02-28T06:00:00.000Z"

//March
moment(["2022","2","31"]).toISOString()
"Invalid date"

moment(["2022","3","30"]).toISOString()
"2022-04-30T05:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","4","31"]).toISOString()
"2022-05-31T05:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","5","30"]).toISOString()
"2022-06-30T05:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","6","31"]).toISOString()
"2022-07-31T05:00:00.000Z"

//August
moment(["2022","7","31"]).toISOString()
"Invalid date"

moment(["2022","8","30"]).toISOString()
"2022-09-30T05:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","9","31"]).toISOString()
"2022-10-31T05:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","10","30"]).toISOString()
"2022-11-30T06:00:00.000Z"
moment(["2022","11","31"]).toISOString()
"2022-12-31T06:00:00.000Z"
```

However, when I specify an integer for the Month parameter, these dates work:

```js
//March
moment(["2022",2,"31"]).toISOString()
"2022-03-31T05:00:00.000Z"

//August
moment(["2022",7,"31"]).toISOString()
"2022-08-31T05:00:00.000Z"
```

I'm wondering why this happens when I pass the Month parameter as a string vs integer?

Comment: Which version of moment.js are you using?

Comment: Somewhat old, I'm realizing... https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out upgrading to the latest version of moment.js fixed it.

Old breaking example ([v2.7.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js)):
https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwauz1t/1/

Latest version working example ([v2.18.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js)):
https://jsfiddle.net/dsadkpsa/

Here's the code being executed in the above links to jsfiddle:

```
console.log(moment(["2022","2","31"]).toISOString());
console.log(moment(["2022",2,"31"]).toISOString());
console.log(moment(["2022","7","31"]).toISOString());
console.log(moment(["2022",7,"31"]).toISOString());
```

Thanks @cochsen for the nudge in the right direction.